# How can I use characters in a function as argument in R?

Tags: r

I want to update a date file which I want to assign weight to a name.

For example :

```
weight_f = function(Name = 0, Weight = 0){ 
        data$Weight = ifelse(data$Name==Name, Weight, NA)
}
```

The problem is that I need to have Name as "Name" after ==. I tried pasting " before and after, but it wont work because R wont let me enter """

Comment: Please consider providing a small input dataset for testing and expected output.  Based on an example I created, it gives the expected ouput thoough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy fix :)

```
weight_f = function(Name = 0, Weight = 0){ 
        data$Weight = ifelse(data$Name==deparse(substitute(Name)), Weight, NA)
}
```

Edit:

Actually, I think I misunderstood what you were asking, and my answer doesn't make any sense because of it (in the case I thought you meant, you would have just used "Name" rather than deparse(substitute(Name)) - same output).

I think probably what you want is `toString` :

```
weight_f = function(Name = 0, Weight = 0){ 
        data$Weight = ifelse(data$Name==toString(Name), Weight, NA)
}
```